# Determining the hash used on a string

Tags: hash

I am building a reports webapp using data from a vendor application. Ideally, I want to piggyback on that applications user authentication system, to keep things simple for everyone. The problem is, I can't seem to figure out how they hash their passwords.

All I know is all the hash's seem to be numeric (of varying length), and that the password `rez` becomes the hash `21159196153202102051222310115574209144220236`. Any idea what they are using?

Comment: It could be anything.  If it's a halfway-decent hash algorithm, there's no way to reverse-engineer it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

Turns out this is nothing but a simple (raw) md5, with each character converted to its ascii value. The following will produce the expected hash

```
$hash = md5("rez", true); 
$temp = str_split($hash);

foreach($temp as $t){
 echo ord($t);
 }
```